# Vuforia Detecting and Tracking Multiple Targets Simultaneously with Cloud

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I use vuforia cloud recognition and I will show 2 targets to camera at the same time. I want to see two object  at the same time but It only can detect one target and show one object. Is it possible to do that with cloud recognition?

I add exapmle picture. I want to see the same time 2 cube together.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jac2P.png)

Comment: Didn't learn anything from your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671299/vuforia-multiple-video-playback#comment72467917_42671299)....

Comment: Unfortunately no @Programmer

Comment: Seriously dude... Give some more info. What exactly is the problem? What did you try? Some code?

Comment: I don't have code because I want to learn this idea is possible but save sample picture @yakobom

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. The Vuforia SDK can track up to five Object Targets simultaneously. This feature can be enabled by providing hints to the Vuforia SDK.

For more details, visit this link [How To Detect and Track Multiple Targets Simultaneously](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Detect-and-Track-Multiple-Targets-Simultaneously)

Comment: Thanks for answer and I find this link but I can't understand. I can't find ObjectTargets.cpp file, ImageTargets.cpp file and EAGLView.mm in my project

Comment: Well than you can post this on their forums or just email at their support.